# How is this debug\AndroidManifest error happen?

Tags: android, android-studio

[The screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnTzd.png)

The project cannot resolve symbol R so I clean the project but the warning is as the pic, how is this happen, I did not do anything to my project.

Comment: There's a space between the 1 and the 0 "1. 0"

Comment: Can try to remove space after `com.pg.MainActivity` ?

Comment: Activity attribute has invalid space character... Read the very specific error message

Comment: The file in your screenshot is not the Manifest file you should be editing - it is the automatically generated one. Look for errors in your project manifest.

Answer (score 3):

You are putting an space character (" ") in your "com.pg.MainActivity" activity name attribute. Remove that space char an it should work like a charm. Also, the aapt error is because your Manifest file cannot be parsed, so the resources indexes cannot be generated (aapt is the program that generates the resources indexes). Also, be sure to edit the manifest file of the "main\AndroidManifest.xml" tab.

Comment: Except the shown image is of the generated manifest, not the project's manifest

Comment: Sure, he needs to edit the manifest of the tab "main\AndroidManifest.xml" of his screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and rebuild project.Then you wont see that error

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra character at the end in **"com.pg.MainActivity"**. 
After this also perform, **Sync Project with gradle files**.
Performing a Make Project after this should resolve the issue.
Try clean and rebuild if it is required.